# Android "Failed to open APK ", "failed to add asset path" & "java.io.IOException: Failed to load asset path"

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, repository-pattern

Failed to open APK '/data/app/~~Binr6SVO9dmLCUcPgCpAyA==/com.example.newspaper-yFV7fjvEt5i0gI4--yMcTA==/base.apk': I/O error
Failed to open APK '/data/app/~~Binr6SVO9dmLCUcPgCpAyA==/com.example.newspaper-yFV7fjvEt5i0gI4--yMcTA==/base.apk': I/O error
failed to add asset path '/data/app/~~Binr6SVO9dmLCUcPgCpAyA==/com.example.newspaper-yFV7fjvEt5i0gI4--yMcTA==/base.apk'
java.io.IOException: Failed to load asset path /data/app/~~Binr6SVO9dmLCUcPgCpAyA==/com.example.newspaper-yFV7fjvEt5i0gI4--yMcTA==/base.apk
at android.content.res.ApkAssets.nativeLoad(Native Method)
at android.content.res.ApkAssets.(ApkAssets.java:295)
at android.content.res.ApkAssets.loadFromPath(ApkAssets.java:144)
at android.app.ResourcesManager.loadApkAssets(ResourcesManager.java:454)
at android.app.ResourcesManager.access$000(ResourcesManager.java:72)
at android.app.ResourcesManager$ApkAssetsSupplier.load(ResourcesManager.java:168)
at android.app.ResourcesManager.createAssetManager(ResourcesManager.java:530)
at android.app.ResourcesManager.createResourcesImpl(ResourcesManager.java:612)
at android.app.ResourcesManager.findOrCreateResourcesImplForKeyLocked(ResourcesManager.java:664)
at android.app.ResourcesManager.createResources(ResourcesManager.java:1011)
at android.app.ResourcesManager.getResources(ResourcesManager.java:1114)
at android.app.ActivityThread.getTopLevelResources(ActivityThread.java:2414)
at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getResourcesForApplication(ApplicationPackageManager.java:1751)
at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getResourcesForApplication(ApplicationPackageManager.java:1737)
at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getDrawable(ApplicationPackageManager.java:1506)
at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.loadUnbadgedItemIcon(ApplicationPackageManager.java:3029)
at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadUnbadgedIcon(PackageItemInfo.java:290)
at com.android.systemui.toast.SystemUIToast.getBadgedIcon(SystemUIToast.java:284)
at com.android.systemui.toast.SystemUIToast.inflateToastView(SystemUIToast.java:198)
at com.android.systemui.toast.SystemUIToast.(SystemUIToast.java:90)
at com.android.systemui.toast.SystemUIToast.(SystemUIToast.java:77)
at com.android.systemui.toast.ToastFactory.createToast(ToastFactory.java:78)
at com.android.systemui.toast.ToastUI.lambda$showToast$0(ToastUI.java:113)
at com.android.systemui.toast.ToastUI.$r8$lambda$w_gPCh3F8Xxn1jN4lkQZoUci71c(Unknown Source:0)
at com.android.systemui.toast.ToastUI$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:16)
at com.android.systemui.toast.ToastUI.showToast(ToastUI.java:140)
at com.android.systemui.statusbar.CommandQueue$H.handleMessage(CommandQueue.java:1441)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7842)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)

I'm using the News API for my news app. These are the steps until the crash :

1. Showing a list of news
2. Click on one of them to show its details into the ArticleFragment
3. When I click on the floatingactionbutton to save it in the SavedNewsFragment, it crashes with the mentioned error.

The related files :

***NewsViewModel***

```
class NewsViewModel(val repo : NewsRepository) : ViewModel()
{
    val breakingNews: MutableLiveData<Resource<NewsResponse>> = MutableLiveData()
    val breakingNewsPage = 1        // update later

    val searchNews: MutableLiveData<Resource<NewsResponse>> = MutableLiveData()
    val searchNewsPage = 1        // update later

    var savedNews: MutableLiveData<List<Article>> = MutableLiveData()

    init {
        getBreakingNews()
    }

/**For BreakingNewsFragment**/
    private fun getBreakingNews(countryString : String = "eg") = viewModelScope.launch {
        breakingNews.postValue(Resource.Loading())
        val response = repo.getBreakingNews(countryString, breakingNewsPage)
        breakingNews.postValue(handleBreakingNewsResponse(response))
    }

    private fun handleBreakingNewsResponse(response: Response<NewsResponse>) : Resource<NewsResponse>
    {
        if(response.isSuccessful)
            response.body().let {
                return Resource.Success(it)
            }
        else
            return Resource.Error(response.message(), response.body())
    }

/**For SearchNewsFragment**/
    fun searchForNews(text : String) = viewModelScope.launch {
        searchNews.postValue(Resource.Loading())
        val response = repo.getSearchedNews(text, searchNewsPage)
        searchNews.postValue(handleSearchForNewsResponse(response))
    }

    private fun handleSearchForNewsResponse(response: Response<NewsResponse>) : Resource<NewsResponse>
    {
        if(response.isSuccessful)
            response.body().let {
                return Resource.Success(it)
            }
        else
            return Resource.Error(response.message(), response.body())
    }

/**Deal with Room**/
    fun saveThisArticle(article: Article) = viewModelScope.launch {
        repo.addIfNotExist(article)
        /*Log.d("NewsViewModel "," => Start saving")
        val num = repo.addIfNotExist(article).wait()
        Log.d("NewsViewModel => saveThisArticle(article: Article) ", "--------- $num")*/
    }

    fun getMySavedArticles() = savedNews.postValue(repo.getSavedNews().value)

    fun deleteThisArticle(article: Article) = viewModelScope.launch {
        repo.deleteArticle(article)
    }


    class NewsVMFactory(val repo: NewsRepository) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
        override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
            if(modelClass.isAssignableFrom(NewsViewModel::class.java)){
                @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
                return NewsViewModel(repo) as T
            }
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown viewModel class")
        }
    }
}
```

***NewsRepository***

```
class NewsRepository(val db: ArticleDatabase)
{
    /**Remote**/
    suspend fun getBreakingNews(country_of_2Letters : String, pageNum : Int) =
        RetrofitInstance.newsAPI.getNewsHeadlines()

    suspend fun getSearchedNews(text : String, pageNum : Int) =
        RetrofitInstance.newsAPI.searchFor(text, pageNum)

    /**Local**/
    suspend fun addIfNotExist(article : Article) =
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            db.newsDatabaseDao.upsert(article)
    }

    fun getSavedNews() = db.newsDatabaseDao.getAllArticles()

    suspend fun deleteArticle(article : Article) = db.newsDatabaseDao.deleteArticle(article)

}
```

***interface NewsDao***

```
@Dao
interface NewsDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun upsert(article : Article): Long      // TODO ???? Int

    @Query("SELECT * FROM articles")
    fun getAllArticles(): LiveData<List<Article>>   // TODO There will be two tables. one for saved articles and other for cashing.

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteArticle(article: Article)

}
```

***ArticleDatabase***

```
@Database(entities = [Article::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
abstract class ArticleDatabase : RoomDatabase() {                                   

    abstract val newsDatabaseDao: NewsDao       

    companion object {

        @Volatile
        var INSTANCE: ArticleDatabase? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): ArticleDatabase {
            synchronized(this) {
                return INSTANCE ?: Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    ArticleDatabase::class.java,
                    "article_database"
                )
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .build()
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**The model/data file**

```
data class NewsResponse(
    val articles: List<Article>,
    val status: String, // ok
    val totalResults: Int // 383
)

@Entity(tableName = "articles")
data class Article(
  //  @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
  //  val id : Int? = null,      // tried: var, Int, Int = 0, Int?
    @ColumnInfo(name = "author")
    val author: String? = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "content")
    val content: String? = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "description")
    val description: String? = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "published_at")
    val publishedAt: String, 
    @ColumnInfo(name = "source")
    val source: Source,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "title")
    val title: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "url")
    val url: String, 
    @ColumnInfo(name = "url_to_image")
    val urlToImage: String?
) : Serializable
{
    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        var result = id.hashCode()
        if(url.isNullOrEmpty()){
            result = 31 * result + url.hashCode()
        }
        return result
    }
}

data class Source(
    val id: String, // business-insider
    val name: String // The Guardian
)
```

***Converters class***

```
class Converters {

//    data class Source(
//    val id: String,
//    val name: String
//    )

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromSource(source: Source): String =
        Gson().toJson(source)      // set in the database as a string

    @TypeConverter
    fun toSource(stringSource: String) : Source =
        Gson().fromJson(stringSource, Source::class.java)      // get it from the database and compose it into its original datatype
}
```

***ArticleFragment***

```
class ArticleFragment : BaseFragment(R.layout.fragment_article) {

    lateinit var binding : FragmentArticleBinding
    val args : ArticleFragmentArgs by navArgs()

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        binding = FragmentArticleBinding.inflate(inflater)

        val data = args.anArticle

        binding.webView.apply {
            try{
                webViewClient = WebViewClient()
                    loadUrl(data.url)
            }
            catch (e: Exception){
                loadUrl("https://www.google.co.in/")
                Toast.makeText(context, "There is a problem in the url", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }

        binding.fab.setOnClickListener {
            viewModel.saveThisArticle(data)
            Toast.makeText(context, "Saved successfully ✅", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        return binding.root
    }


    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        binding.unbind()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you check if the `author` field is not null in the fab's onClick?

Comment: Well, I removed 'author' and 'content', but a new error occurred.

Failed to open APK '/data/app/~~Binr6SVO9dmLCUcPgCpAyA==/com.example.newspaper-yFV7fjvEt5i0gI4--yMcTA==/base.apk': I/O error
Failed to open APK '/data/app/~~Binr6SVO9dmLCUcPgCpAyA==/com.example.newspaper-yFV7fjvEt5i0gI4--yMcTA==/base.apk': I/O error
failed to add asset path '/data/app/~~Binr6SVO9dmLCUcPgCpAyA==/com.example.newspaper-yFV7fjvEt5i0gI4--yMcTA==/base.apk'
java.io.IOException: Failed to load asset path /data/app/~~Binr6SVO9dmLCUcPgCpAyA==/com.example.newspaper-yFV7fjvEt5i0gI4--yMcTA==/base.apk

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: found any luck?

Comment: The problems are caused by `Toast`

Comment: This happened due to Toast as stated above by Tran. Wiping the emulator and re-running the app made the error go away for me.

Comment: Could you be more specific?